# LWC getter not returning value

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to build an increment counter in LWC that is fairly straight forward but keeps throwing invariant violations if I try to do any math inside the getter. I have tried a variety of different iterations of this all with no success. from declaring the `rowNumber` function as @api, using a setter, and, also tracking `{counter]` instead of rowNumber. The reason I am having an issue with this is because I need to print out iterating number , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4. If I track the counter, I only end up printing out the last number. On the html side, this is inside a template for loop fyi.So, what I am trying to accomplish on the html side is call a variable or function-return, and print a number, starting with 1, counting up to the nTH. any thoughts?

```
**JS**
@api counter = 1;

get rowNumber(){
return this.counter++;

**html**
<div>{rowNumber}</div>
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to directly update API properties from within the component. You should be receiving an error because of the attempt to increment the API property in the `rowNumber` getter.

Comment: In your HTML, what are you using as the array for your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify an `@api` property. Getter modifying a field is also a bad practice.

In the `for:each` tag you can use the index variable by setting the for:index variable. The index starts with 0 but you can pass it to the @api property and increase it by 1 in your getter.
Parent component html:

```
<template for:each={yourCollection} for:item="item" for:index="index">
    <c-component index={index}></c-component>
</template>
```

component.js

```
@api index;
get rowNumber() {
    return this.index+1;
}
```

Comment: `return this.index+1;`. Forgetting the `this.` is rather common.

Comment: @sfdcfox edited, thanks

Comment: i tried this but it returns nothing. i was already using index in my for loop but it starts with 0 so that doesnt work. note : i am not using a parent/child component, so i can't call line 2 in your html. i also tried declaring the getter with @api.

Comment: @sesanc If I understand you right, what you are trying to achieve is to render the same variable in several places in a way that it has different values in each place. That's not possible, the newest variable value will be rendered at all times. You need to redesign your code to either use child components as above, or modify the collection that you are iterating over so that it includes the row number.

Comment: you were correct on the child component. works. muchas gracias!